# Wordpress, what is the easiest way to block extern stylesheet?

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I'm currentry trying to switch from extern fontawesome to local. I implemented the local fontawesome, but I can't find a solution to blocklist the extern stylesheets, which are added by Plugins.

I tried to find the handle of the stylesheet enqueue. Couldn't find the handle and it wouldn't make much sense, since many plugins could be importing fontawesome

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *wp_print_styles* action hook that is triggered before stylesheets are printed to the page. Try adding this code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function remove_plugin_stylesheet() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'style-handle' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'style-handle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_plugin_stylesheet', 100 );
```

Also, don't forget to replace the 'style-handle' parameter with the actual ID of the stylesheet you want to remove. Feel free to refer to this example in case you can't find it → https://prnt.sc/fXo-J1UiCLwY

Comment: Unfortunately, the stylesheet has no id